# How to call a method when a form is submitted on a JSF page?

Tags: jsf, el

What I basically want to do is, when the user submits the form, a method should be called, which is not a setter.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<h:form>
    <p>
        Your guess: <h:inputText value="#{quizBean.someMethod()}"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit answer"/>
    </p>
</h:form>
```

It does not work with **#{quizBean.someMethod}** either.

If I create a field called **someMethod** and generate **getters and setters** for it, it will work fine.

Is there anyway to do this?

My web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

I am running this on Tomcat 7.0 and using **jsf-api:2.1.19** and **jsf-impl:2.1.19** jars.

This is the exception I am getting:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /index.xhtml @23,71 value="#{quizBean.someMethod()}": Property 'someMethod' not found on type com.tugay.problems.QuizBean
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The `value` attribute must evaluate to a `property` expression (with its `get` method). Moreover, if the control is not readonly, a `set` method must also be provided.

Other attributes (like the `action` attribute from `h:commandButton`) accept expressions that do evaluate to a method in the bean, but not this one.

The only workaround is what you already did, making the `get` implement `someMethod`. Be careful that I am not sure the method will be called when rendering a JSF page.

Answer (score 1):

You want to call a method on form submit? This is exactly what `h:commandButton` is made for. Just add the `action` attribute to your command button and point it to an action method like this:

```
<h:inputText value="#{quizBean.answer}"/>
<h:commandButton value="Submit answer" action="#{quizBean.submitAnswer}"/>
```

The method on your bean should look like this:

```
public String submitAnswer() {
  // Do something with property answer
  return null;
}
```

As the action method is called after the values from the input components are stored, you can access them without problems. The return value is used for navigation by JSF. It can contain a view ID or a navigation outcome. If the return value is null, JSF stays on the same page.

Comment: Well, what I wanted to do is actually get the input from a textfield, and call a method with its value. I guess it is impossible. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's not exactly the way JSF works (for this case). Just use a value expression for a property on the bean like `<h:inputText value="#{quizBean.answer}"/>`. Then you can use the value of the `answer` property in the action method.